# php pagination just changing the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i've cretated pagination in php, when i click to the next page, just the url changing, not the table

this my index url:
localhost/web_name

and this my pagination url:
localhost/web_name/paging (url condition in first load)
localhost/web_name/paging?halaman=2 (url condition after click to the next page)

url changing to localhost/web_name/paging?halaman=2 but, it didn't change the data that i display.

this my index.php code

```
<?php
//main page
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : "main";
switch ($page) {
  case 'upload':
    include "upload.php";
    break;
  case 'paging':
    include "paging.php";
    break;
  case 'main':
  default:
    include "upload.php";
}
?>
```

this my paging.php code https://gist.github.com/mupinnn/51b6fe8d5ce068368a29d581e6ea0620

and this my htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^paging index.php?page=paging [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^upload index.php?page=upload [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is not a solution but a suggestion to do `RewriteRule ^paging index.php/paging [NC,L]` and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get what was requested. This is to act as a fail-safe in case the user requests `paging?page=upload` which will mess up the query string

Comment: is it safe to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then i dont need `$_GET['page']` anymore? that will work the same way?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is probably as safe as `$_GET` both are user controlled so you'd need to exercise the same type of caution when using either, however using  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will reduce the likelihood someone creates a bad link by mistake since it's much harder to navigate to your `index.php` than it is to change a query parameter

Comment: i've been changing to ur suggestion, the url changing when i click link to the another page, but the content not. `$page = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "main";` i'm keep using the switch, am i wrong?

Comment: I think in this case you need to add slashes to the cases e.g. `case '/paging':`

Comment: it doesn't work too. i think the htaccess not working properly. `^paging index.php/paging` when i click `<a href="paging">paging</a>` it's just change the url from `localhost/web_name/index.php or localhost/web_name/ to localhost/web_name/paging`